# Visual Studio 2010 Weird Bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have been using visual studio 2010 for quite some time now.. and this is the first time that I have encountered a weird bug, I don't even know how to search it on the web.
So here it is, when I open Visual Studio 2010, Go on 'File', then click 'Open Project', nothing happens. It just closes the menu and then nothing happens.
This also happens when I add a reference to my project. Still the same. Somehow the problem is related to 'opening a file'. 
Did someone have this problem before?
Please change my title if it doesn't fit to my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Using visual studio 2010 for all my work, even though it is a setting in my opinion very good, but sometimes I have all sorts of problems. Sometimes problems blockers like what you describe.

In my case I always solutions consist of many projects.
Usually to restart VS2010 do so.

1) I create a new solution
2) Add a project
3) Compile the code, Lunch  the program and if I do ok editing and repeat compile and run.
4) Repeat step 2

This has saved me many times:-)

I hope you can be useful.
Let me know.